# How does defining cell assembly by giving weightage to impact caused as opposed to strength of connections change our current paradigm?

Tags: neuroscience, cell-signaling, synapses, artificial-neural-network

Buzsaki, in his paper [Neural Syntax: Cell Assemblies, Synapsembles, and Readers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3005627/), seems to suggest that instead of using synaptic strength and connectivity as a defining feature, a (dynamically changing constellation of) neural cell assemblies could instead be classified based on the impact/output caused by their target "reader" neurons.

Primary question:
**Is this an accurate reading of the argument?**

His argument, in my understanding, is that the strength of upstream connectivities may not have a biologically meaningful significance unless the downstream potential is interpreted and acted on by the target reader neuron. Hence, interpreting the output/impact caused by the action potential of the reader neuron would provide insight into the nature of transiently formed assemblies as opposed to tracking down the linkages.

Therefore, while the synaptic strength of upstream neural assemblies increases the likelihood of stronger downstream potential, it need not be a requirement as even weakly connected upstream assemblies can gain significance if they activate the target layer. (Hence, the temporal window is a more deterministic classifier).

Secondary question:
**Are there any compelling counterarguments to this hypothesis in the literature? Ideally including data supporting one hypothesis or another?**

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the paper or provide a full reference. I'm not sure the question is answerable with anything but opinion and discussion though. Your post also seems to take as a straw man the idea that strength of connection is otherwise the sole defining feature - is anyone arguing that?

Comment: you might consider having this quesiton migrated to the [psych/neuroscience SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/). That might yield a slightly more relevant/expert group. I also second the suggestion to link the paper directly and try to find a more specific/answerable framing.